# I'm tryng to get 15 minutes data from an investing chart using Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, request

Using Network in Chrome I can see the data in "history?symbol" . I'm trying to use requests to retrieve the data from the server but i get a "wrong" answer.

Here you can see the data.

[image: history]

I tried to include all Request headers:

```
import requests as r

headers = {

headers = {

'authority': 'tvc6.investing.com',
'method': 'GET',
'path': '/2d19c201b143891a2a93d0dac067cd2f/1671821408/9/9/16/history?symbol=8826&resolution=15&from=1670525414&to=1671821474',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'content-type': 'text/plain',
'origin': 'https://tvc-invdn-com.investing.com',
'referer': 'https://tvc-invdn-com.investing.com/',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


url = 'ttps://tvc6.investing.com/9768149495242e3a981657248a331375/1671817931/9/9/16/history?symbol=169&resolution=D&from=1640713937&to=1671817997'

res = r.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res.text)
```

At this point i expected to get the quotes instead this is output of res.text :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

</head>
<body class="no-js">
    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1 class="zone-name-title h1">
            <img class="heading-favicon" src="/favicon.ico"
                 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
            tvc6.investing.com
        </h1>
        <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
            Checking if the site connection is secure
        </h2>
        <noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=77e333dbcb67baa9')"></div>
        <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">
            tvc6.investing.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
        </div>
        <form id="challenge-form" action="/f40164d944674ed76becf8db0e9c14b0/1671820539/9/9/16/history?symbol=169&amp;resolution=D&amp;from=1640716550&amp;to=1671820611&amp;__cf_chl_f_tk=PAKC13kdHaKQTG3W4_hgr.5.RMPMRkeKVU2SUyk09ro-1671820584-0-gaNycGzNB-U" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="md" value="J.f3.wMZ.BNTJYPadA1vYlaXEyX0q0O.2lARxYp8Hpo-1671820584-0-ATK8iV0CZVOWRlqDK62tq_XSUSX20BbMR2OvQfb2HEl3tlNNeozMBAaRzucZ-JQASJwYKAFRvecMyxBbNUH44941PhGo6CVJrssNYwnHJwBx5XHKTXwGGPMUXbR8T0MEBi2hzsic-320H9ZlYQlGI349dbpFIhxGFDR0-C9IF_2rqCHiBt6NoWfs-vef2peqxQwgWBsWBiGWgxOUV3a1Fs3hHxBvKlOmIuMuDiqqdTyhp6-vZMfsyeFzvPP2zHeq8xcV2-avF3_9ZYDiNSOzE8LeLVf5S7JIPuQzFFSJ8F_wigow__c3AtLiEK-YIhOep_GROBBGqFg6eeQR_6IDuv-pvNiVyixPwL6M4pK-_CCt1Yz9EZT2yPDEK-xGIFKb57OU53cYKVRIFoGM05V1Vi7CyuJ2R7-l6xGd9PWqjTmElNpYr6LWixAvbXw4iXxBG7M5MT3UPNJSmvjcl8pLarK7nRueANA7_JLAypHzGDJbIeZZjDGR-_wD7OxiMq7_HjDbrXNxico6Hm-Y0ufOhFOBs0pTXQh50qwWZuZQR2wI24zNAD-C9MbSByhImb64BKbJUjEkQ42WUd1nAvfWFHCI7_CQNefj_4ODtiQuv6MUIu4Soh3q-ziA5p3MGPQ9oja-G6lcOTbDWRdDXN2SiO9iC_lHStuIGmPpnndCtYNdXHHoROsj08J8SDrumhgQakSvqz5TOuEhM_cPD3fgfcdfUfsXMxONrcr5tr_pW5GIZxT-yNMwZPCCOuk3tHp9gpoHswT21VAvJmW3-tUUKhqv1tAJ2YjyOq5GSk-B2Od1IUHAYEjLo7VLx9nj1e3KSrLqbk-rk_88tnmXwqlO9ll0gCeD0Yd6Ay9pDO--BLxuqlm8oKCUKcdTJGDW2Upk5GXzql4Z7KAsrvbb5WxYpD_WUN8vQoiVv-NWX8n4ayzhRqIJI8dJMhO8VRYyVCU4BQ">
            <input type="hidden" name="r" value="HJnrCKhJ_gjr.LD3n579C0trZHejKyPIuY_UoC.XofQ-1671820584-0-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">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '90776',
            cRay: '77e333dbcb67baa9',
            cHash: 'f11ad78e5776344',
            cUPMDTk: "\/f40164d944674ed76becf8db0e9c14b0\/1671820539\/9\/9\/16\/history?symbol=169&resolution=D&from=1640716550&to=1671820611&__cf_chl_tk=PAKC13kdHaKQTG3W4_hgr.5.RMPMRkeKVU2SUyk09ro-1671820584-0-gaNycGzNB-U",
            cFPWv: 'g',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cTplV: 4,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly90dmM2LmludmVzdGluZy5jb20vZjQwMTY0ZDk0NDY3NGVkNzZiZWNmOGRiMGU5YzE0YjAvMTY3MTgyMDUzOS85LzkvMTYvaGlzdG9yeT9zeW1ib2w9MTY5JnJlc29sdXRpb249RCZmcm9tPTE2NDA3MTY1NTAmdG89MTY3MTgyMDYxMQ==',
                ra: 'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzEwOC4wLjAuMCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2',
                rm: 'UE9TVA==',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY3MTgyMDU4NC4yOTUwMDA=',
                m: 'L1y5xK1/Sq7cd5oLYYhW4KwqKSOAa3n71efNpVtp3+g=',
                i1: 'q+IjrBusVkHd4eEfQRD10A==',
                i2: '953cHnmvQ+drrrrvPtwV4A==',
                zh: 'JJQg2KI/+bPgJbLHlLjmrs/mnno8aAGH5k3tm8QDk4c=',
                uh: 'JkAkY486s8b7quQvdaIQRGNNNpmu+ejtUZNcz6o7wFM=',
                hh: 'BOEQT4xQDG4tL5g1V86g4le5vNzUl5zMva+mAqYjhqI=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=77e333dbcb67baa9');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=77e333dbcb67baa9';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/f40164d944674ed76becf8db0e9c14b0\/1671820539\/9\/9\/16\/history?symbol=169&resolution=D&from=1640716550&to=1671820611&__cf_chl_rt_tk=PAKC13kdHaKQTG3W4_hgr.5.RMPMRkeKVU2SUyk09ro-1671820584-0-gaNycGzNB-U" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>


    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">
                <div class="ray-id">Ray ID: <code>77e333dbcb67baa9</code></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">Performance &amp; security by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=m" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are using CloudFlare to protect their website, you won't be able to download this information. Not to mention you have multiple syntax errors in your code.

Comment: I am confusing, Do you want to OHLC chart by Python with request? or HTML/Javascript/Axios for OHLC chart?

Comment: OHLC chart by Python